# What is the best way to upload large data set to tarantool

Tags: c#, sql, tarantool

I have defined a simple table in Tarantool and I'm trying to fulfil it with 1 millions of record. I'm using a c# code with progaudi.tarantool library. I'm using two approaches:

`box.ExecuteSql(/*My insert statement*/)`
and
`space.Insert<Item>(item)`

Both are extremlly slow. Using `box.stat()` in the terminal I can see that I'm able to insert only 63 requests per second.

I haven't noticed any approach where I can do the bulk insert. I tried to send a multiple sql statements but it's failing. Is there any approach that I can use to upload data quickly  or investigate why only 63 insert requests per second are done?

Edit 1:
I found the following information when executing `box.slab.info()`

```
- items_size: 32203920
   items_used_ratio: 97.42%   !!
quota_size: 268435456   
quota_used_ratio: 18.75%   
arena_used_ratio: 82.1%   
items_used: 31373320   
quota_used: 50331648   
arena_size: 50331648   
arena_used: 41302024 ...
```

Those settings were defined:

```
 box.cfg{memtx_max_tuple_size=100*1048576}
 box.cfg{memtx_memory=3*268435456}
```

Comment: I don't know specifics of the C# connector, but I can give several usual suggestions:

1. Use asynchronous requests (if the connector supports it).
2. Or use batching (define a Lua procedure, which accepts a list of tuples and inserts them **in a transaction** — use `box.atomic()`). Call this procedure with batches of 1000 tuples or so.

I see there is a related issue: https://github.com/progaudi/progaudi.tarantool/issues/127

Comment: @AlexanderTurenko Thanks I will do what you described. I started wondering that maybe the issue is somewhere else - in the memory. I updated post providing some information about memory statistics. It's 2.8 version executed in docker.

Comment: If you can extract a small reproducer (without your private code / data), it would help to spot a real problem.

Comment: @AdamŁepkowski I am new on Tarantool did you solve problem help share answer

Comment: @Meas no. I was trying to solve it during our POC and we made decision to not use Tarantool for our purpose. It's great tool but not for our business scenarios.